# Google Maps API for Business limitations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, licensing

Trying to figure out the limitations of the Google Maps API for Business.

It appears that usage limit is 100K loads/day per one Business account ([here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits)). A business account can  include a number of authorized URLs (up to 100), which can be as general as domains ([here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/troubleshooting_auth#basics)). Meanwhile, a single website can load up to 25K loads/day for free ([here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits)).

So my main question is - seems the Business account doesn't get you all that much in terms of usage limits - and actually hurts you in case you have several domains (e.g., 8 domains which would have 200K combined limit (25Kx8) in the free case, but only 100K in case of using Business account). Is that how it works?

A smaller question: are there limitations on which URLs can be authorized? (I.e., do they have to be within the same TLD or not)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/369450)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an M4B license I would encourage you to contact M4B Tech Support team:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#support

If you do not have access, but are using M4B then fill in this form:
http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142246#q3

There are number of reasons why you would like a M4B license. Some customers buy it for interbal pageviews, some for the increased Web Service quotas and others for the Tech Support and SLAs.

If you would like to know more you can contact the Google Sales team:
http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html

Regarding the TLDs, the answer is no. They can be any http or https URLs.

HTH